# If one considers any number not divisible by $p$ and multiply it with each of the numbers $1,2,3\cdots\cdots p-1$, what happens?

Tags: number-theory

If one considers any number not divisible by $p$ and multiply it with each of the numbers $1,2,3\cdots\cdots p-1$, in turn one will get $p−1$ different numbers modulo p. How can we prove this?

Note: p is prime here

I googled it, but not finding required proof.

Comment: "do you know that each of those integers is invertible modulo p", no I don't know. Yes p is prime here. Can you tell me the proof step-wise. I am new to number theory

Comment: Did you see the ring   of congruence classes $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$?

Answer (score 5):

Let $x$ not be a multiple of $p$, and assume that $a$ and $b$ are such that $xa\equiv xb\pmod{p}$. Then $p\mid xa-xb = x(a-b)$. Since $p$ does not divide $x$ and is prime, then $p\mid a-b$, hence $a\equiv b\pmod{p}$.

By contrapositive, if $a\not\equiv b\pmod{p}$, then $xa\not\equiv xb\pmod{p}$.

Comment: see I understood this much you said $xa$%$p$$=xb$%$p$, where % denotes modulo

If we can prove a=b, then we are done. $a\in \{1,2,3\cdots\cdots p-1\}, b\in \{1,2,3\cdots\cdots p-1\}$. How can we proceed from here.

Comment: @user3290550: If $1\leq a,b\leq p-1$, and say $a\geq b$; then $0\leq a-b\lt p$. How many of those numbers are multiples of $p$?

Comment: Given a group $G$ with $x\in G$, is this just a special case of the fact that the map $G\to G$ by $a\mapsto xa$ is a bijection?

Comment: ok so you are saying that if $xa \equiv xb \mod n$, then $x(a-b)=0 \mod n$. As $x$ is not divisible by $p$, then it means $(a-b)$ is divisible by $p$. Now as $a<p$ and $b<p$, so $-p<a-b<p$, so only number in this range which is divisible by $p$ is $0$, so it means $a-b$ has to be zero in order to be divisible by p, it means $a=b$

Comment: @SantanaAfton: If you already knew that the set in question is a group under multiplication, etc., but since the OP does not yet know that a number is invertible modulo $p$ if and only if it is not divisible modulo $p$, how exactly would you establish that you have a group?

Comment: @user3290550: Well, I'm implying it; you're the one actually saying it. :-)

Comment: Trying to prove If $xa \equiv xb \mod n$, then $x(a−b) \equiv 0 \mod n$? I tried to do in this way, is it correct

$a=pm_1+r_1$,

$b=pm_2+r_2$,

$(a-b)=p(m_1-m_2)+r_1-r_2$

Comment: @user3290550: By definition, $r\equiv s\pmod{n}$ if and only if $n|r-s$. What definition are **you** using?

Comment: I was trying to prove that definition

Comment: @user3290550: You don't prove definitions. Definitions **are**.

Comment: I think you missed something. Definitions are ? :)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, if you want to solve a question based on this fact , here is the one 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3464568/let-p-be-an-odd-prime-number-and-t-p-be-the-following-set-of-2-%C3%97-2-matrice/3464581?noredirect=1#3464581

Comment: @user3290550: Yes; a definition just **is**. You *define* something, and then that's what that something means. You don't "prove* definitions, any more than I "prove" that $1+1$ means "add one to one". Now, there may be many different ways of defining something, and then you may want to prove that the many different definitions yield the same objects (that the definitions are equivalent). But you still need an original meaning for the statement from which you want to derive another. My **definition** of the symbols $r\equiv s\pmod{n}$ *is* $n|r-s$. The two are *exactly the same*, by definition

Comment: So you can't "prove" this definition, unless you have a **different** way of defining the meaning of "$r\equiv s\pmod{n}$." Hence my question: what definition are **you** using? You must be using some definition, otherwise, you are just manipulating symbols with no meaning to them.

Comment: "If you want to solve a question based on this fact". I have no idea what fact "this" refers to. The government doesn't like it when I read minds without a warrant, so I try not to.

Comment: yeah, I once read, that if you want to prove $1+1=2$, then you have to assume that number line is straight, left to right. Because if it had curves or circular like $-2\rightarrow -1\rightarrow 0 \rightarrow 1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow -2$ like this then we will get different results on addition.

Comment: @user3290550: That is not what I said, and that has nothing to do with what I said. What I said is that the symbols "$1+1$" are **defined** to mean "add 1 to 1". There's nothing to prove about whether $1+1$ means "add one to one". that's what the symbols are defined to *mean*. It's not about what the result of the operation is. But what you are telling me is like saying "I am trying to prove that $1+1$". And that's nonsense.

Comment: I also wanted to know about the statement you said, "a number is invertible modulo p if and only if it is not divisible modulo p". I didn't understand this. Can you please explain.

Comment: @user3290550: I can, but it seems like a bit of a waste of my time; it is not relevant to your question, as in fact your question is about **avoiding** that fact in establishing what you want, which is what I provided.

Comment: can you describe me in chat, if not here. I want to know it.

Comment: @user3290550: Then look it up or ask it in a question. I don't do chat.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is only for beginners like me, after reading this anybody can understand why this is true.

Here we assumed two different numbers $a,b$ where $0\le a<p$ and $0\le b<p$ and assumed $xa≡xb \mod n$. So in the last if we can prove $a=b$, then we are done.

If $xa≡xb \mod n$, then $x(a−b)\equiv 0 \mod n$. As $x$ is not divisible by $p$, then it means $(a−b)$ has to be divisible by $p$. Now as $0\le a<p$ and $0\le b<p$, so $−p<a−b<p$, so only number in this range which is divisible by $p$ is $0$, so it means $a−b$ has to be zero in order to be divisible by $p$, it means $a=b$

Answer (score 0):

Euclids lemma..... If $p$ is prime and $p|MN$ then $p|M$ or $p|N$.

Proof by contrapositive..... If we can prove $ka\equiv kb\pmod p;a,b\in 1,...,p-1 \implies a=b$ that is enough to prove if $a\ne b;a,b\in 1,...,p-1\implies ka \not \equiv kb \pmod p$.....

Definition .... $a \equiv b \pmod p$ means *by definition* $p\mid a-b$....

====

Suppose $p \not \mid k$.  But suppose $ka \equiv kb\pmod p$.

Then by definition $p|ka-kb = k(a-b)$.

By Euclid's lemma that means $p|k$ or $p|a-b$.  But we are given the $p\not \mid k$ so $p|a-b$.

Which by definition means $a\equiv b\pmod p$.

.....

If on the other hand $a \not \equiv b \pmod p$ it would be impossible for $ak \equiv bk$

So if $a \not \equiv b \pmod p$ then $ak \not \equiv bk \pmod p$ for any $k$ not divisible by $p$.

And as the different values of $1,...,p-1$ are in different classes (why?) then the different values of $k, 2k,....,k(p-1)$ will be in different classes.

......

Okay.... a *direct* proof.

Let $a,b \in 1,...,p-1$ and $a \ne b$ and $p\not \mid k$.

First notice that the multiples of $p$ are $...., -3p, -2p,-p,0,p,2p,3p.....$ and if we have $-p < a-b < p$ and $a-b \ne 0$ then $p$ can not divide $a-b$.

And that *is* the case we have.  $a\ne b$ so $a-b \ne 0$  And $a < p$ and $b > 0$ so $a-b < p$.  And $a>0$ and $p <p$ so $a-b > -p$.

So we know $p\not \mid a-b$.

And we know $p\not \mid k$.

So, as $p$ is prime $p\not \mid k(a-b)$....( Hmm... okay, that is the converse of Euclid's lemma--  If $p|MN$ then $p|M$ or $p|N$ so if $p\not \mid M$ and $p\not \mid N$ then $p \not \mid MN$--  so this prove isn't *entirely* direct...)

So $p\not \mid k$ and $p\not \mid a-b$ so $p\not \mid k(a-b) = ka-kb$.

So $ka \not \equiv kb \pmod p$.